# Python How replace word in array?

Tags: python-2.7

i have this code:

```
word = ["General William Shelton, said the system",
        "which will provide more precise positional data",
        "and that newer technology will provide more",
        "Commander of the Air Force Space Command",
        "objects and would become the most accurate metadata"]
```

i wan to replace:

```
Replace “the” with “THE”, “
Replace “William Shelton” with “AliBaba”
Replace “data” with “SAMSUNG”
```

the output should be:

```
 General AliBaba,said THE system which will provide more precise
 positional SAMSUNG and that newer technology will provide more
 Commander of the Air Force Space Command objects and would become the
 most accurate metadata
```

Thank you!

I have tried this:

```
rep_word = {"the":"THE", "William Shelton":"AliBaba", "system":"Samsung"}
replace = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(rep_word.keys()) + r')\b')
result = replace.sub(lambda x: rep_word[x.group()], word)
print result
```

but i got this error : TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far ?

Comment: i just got an error.. i had edited in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use python built function "reduce":

```
def change(prev, s):
     ret = s.replace("the", "THE")
     ret = ret.replace("William Shelton","AliBaba")
     ret = ret.replace("data", "SAMSUNG")
     return prev+' '+ret

reduce(change, word, '')
```

Comment: then how to print it out?

Comment: @wanmohdpayed X = reduce(change, word, '') and then you can print the variable content: print X

Comment: Note that word 'metadata' in source text was not changed, but your code will replace it with "metaSAMSUNG".

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
word = ["General William Shelton, said the system",
        "which will provide more precise positional data",
        "and that newer technology will provide more",
        "Commander of the Air Force Space Command",
        "objects and would become the most accurate metadata"]
replacements = [("the", "THE"), ("William Shelton", "AliBaba"), ("data", "SAMSUNG")]
compiled = [(re.compile(r'\b%s\b' % re.escape(s)), d) for s, d in replacements]
replaced = [reduce(lambda s,(regex,res): regex.sub(lambda _: res, s), compiled, w) for w in word]
result = ' '.join(replaced)
result
'General AliBaba, said THE system which will provide more precise positional SAMSUNG and that newer technology will provide more Commander of THE Air Force Space Command objects and would become THE most accurate metadata'
```

Answer (score 0):

*x* is a string. And use *x*.replace("X","Y"). (Replace X with Y).

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into [Link Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
word = [words.replace('the','THE') for words in word];
```